# Scaling a html canvas

Tags: javascript, vue.js, canvas

I have a canvas:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"/>
```

that I want to be able to scale dynamically using javascript, so I want to use `scale()`. But this is not working:

```
document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('2d').scale(2, 2);
```

The canvas remains at 400x400, even though I want it to be 800x800.

Live demo at https://jsfiddle.net/c8sjpr37/3/ using vue. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: [`.scale()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/scale) changes the scale of things you draw, it doesn't change the size of the canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scale command is an internal canvas command. It changes the scale at which things are drawn. For example:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.strokeRect(5, 5, 25, 15);
ctx.scale(2, 2);
ctx.strokeRect(5, 5, 25, 15);
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"/>
</div>
```

This snippet displays a rectangle, and then another rectangle twice the size of the first one and twice the distance from the translation point, because all of the pixel values were doubled with the `.scale()` command. I don't think this is what you wanted.

There is a way to edit the height and width styling, though. Canvases are picky, so if you change one, the other will change to match the initial ratio, but you can do this with something like:

```
document.getElementById("canvas").style.height = "800px";
```